# Need fullscreen Cordova Inappbrowser on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar, inappbrowser

I need to make my app fullscreen like Google Maps (with content all over display including status bar).

I was able to make html body fullscreen.

But I can't make inappbrowser to use all body height. It starts below status bar.

How can I make inappbrowser starts on body top?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

inappbrowser respects whatever setting you have for your app.
You have two options:

1. hide the status bar for the entire app
2. modify the native code to hide the status bar when inappbrowser is called.